# Copy/paste a range from one sheet to several others depending on the value of a cell in a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a spreadsheet, I have a tab "CUSTOMERS" with values in the range B4:Q,.
These values are imported from another spreadsheet with importrange.

In C4:C of "CLIENTS", there are the names of 3 products which correspond to the names of 3 other tabs ("DATA", "EPHAD", "LIVRET") which have the same column format as the tab "CLIENTS".

What I would like to do is to copy all the values from the range B4:Q of "CLIENTS" and paste them into the tabs that correspond to the product (DATA rows in the DATA tab, EPHAD in the EPHAD tab and LIVRET tab in LIVRET).

I don't just import via FILTER, QUERY or another function because I need the imported content to be editable.

Here is my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTSTb8MlLyncgaEAPY5GwEeRY0qGy7B8UbuzjpiXZEI/edit#gid=0) (the tab "SOURCE IMPORTRANGE" is not there on the original table. I simply inserted the values from the source file into it).

I tried to write a script but I can't get it to work properly.
Here is the script:

```
function UpdateClients() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NTSTb8MlLyncgaEAPY5GwEeRY0qGy7B8UbuzjpiXZEI');
  var sourceValues = sss.getSheetByName("CLIENTS").getDataRange().getValues();  
  
try{
 //DATA
  var tdata = sourceValues.filter(function (row) {
    return row[2] == "DATA";
  }); 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA")
  ss.getRange(4,2, 900, 17).clearContent()
  ss.getRange(4, 2, tdata.length,17).setValues(tdata);

}
catch(e){console.log(e)}
 
 try{
  //EPHAD
  var tephad = sourceValues.filter(function (row) {
    return row[2] == "EPHAD";
  }); 

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EPHAD")
  ss.getRange(4,2, 900, 17).clearContent()
  ss.getRange(4, 2, tephad.length,17).setValues(tephad);

  }
catch(e){console.log(e)}

try{
  //LIVRET
  var tlivret = sourceValues.filter(function (row) {
    return row[2] == "LIVRET";
  }); 

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LIVRET")
  ss.getRange(4,2, 900, 17).clearContent()
  ss.getRange(4, 2, tlivret.length,17).setValues(tlivret);

  }
catch(e){console.log(e)}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Distributing Rows to sheets named in Column C

```
function updateClients() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  const sh = sss.getSheetByName("CLIENTS");
  const vs = sh.getRange("B4:Q" + getColumnHeight(2,sh,sss)).getValues();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const csh = ss.getSheetByName("COMMENTAIRES");
  csh.getRange(4,2,csh.getLastRow() - 3,csh.getLastColumn() - 1).clearContent();
  csh.getRange(4,2,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  let oObj = { sA: [] };//collects rows into 2D arrays
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!oObj.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      oObj.sA.push(r[1]);
      oObj[r[1]] = [];
      oObj[r[1]].push(r);
    } else {
      oObj[r[1]].push(r)
    }
  });
  oObj.sA.forEach(n => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    if (sh.getLastRow() > 3) {
      sh.getRange(4, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 3, sh.getLastColumn() - 1).clearContent();
    }
    sh.getRange(4, 2, oObj[n].length, oObj[n][0].length).setValues(oObj[n]);//outputting 2d arrays from oObj
  });
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cooper, the script work good. You think I can find a solution for onEdit()?

Comment: There is no trigger that fires on a formula changing it's value

Comment: I think running this on the edits of users would probably greatly the delay the editing process.  Personally, I would not do it that way for myself.  It would have to be done line by line and again were still foiled by that fact that there is no trigger which detect changes in formulas

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: I tested this myself and it works for me so if you can tell which line is causing the error then I can probably fix it.

Comment: It looks like  one of your sheet names from column C in CLIENTS does not exist in the activeSpreadsheet.   You can use the debug to confirm that

Comment: The problems was that getLastRow() was not working.  It probably was being corrupted by some other information or formulas on you page.  It was saying the last row was 997 when in fact the last row was 164.  I used another function call getColumnHeight() to fix the problem.  It's in you sheet posted from another account.

Comment: When I ran the code all of the sheets were distributed

Comment: Okay, it's perfect, and it's possible that before pasting in each of the 3 tabs, to paste the whole range in "COMMENTAIRES"?

Comment: I do not understand `paste the whole range in "COMMENTAIRES"?`

Comment: Range B4:Q from "CLIENTS" tab to "COMMENTAIRES" tab after or before to paste it in "DATA","EPHAD" and "LIVRET"

Comment: I don't see why not.  Do you want to append it or replace the entire contents with it

Comment: I would like to replace all the contents

Comment: Thank you all is perfect now!, I added onOpen() function to run the script. I need one last script for this sheet but I will try to do it by myself.. If I need help I will come back here.

Comment: What is your second script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73391336/copy-paste-only-one-edited-cell-in-a-range-in-another-sheet-in-the-row-that-matc

Comment: Okay, but why? Is my question stupid, or is the problem too simple or too complicated?

Comment: I did not say that it was stupid.   I have learned to refrain from such responses

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to modify your script to add function. Could you just tell me if it's possible or not, or too complicated or not without necessarily answering please. I'm asking you because many people don't understand what I need and because you wrote it at least you'll understand. Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73466449/background-colors-remain-frozen-when-new-values-are-added-by-another-script

Comment: Well I can tell you that the problem with a lot of questions is that they represent the final piece of code that the questioner desires to end up with instead of a small piece of code that makes it easy for the person answering the question  to understand the question.  And in this case the code looks a lot like I wrote it so to honest I'm not really that interested in writing it again.  Are you familiar with the term `tl:dr`.  For me at least that's the way I fell about the question.

Comment: I understand. I'm good with formulas but I've only been interested in Apps Script for a month. I am not familiar with tl:dr but I will do my research. Thank you for answering me and giving me a research way.