# Copy/paste edited cells in several ranges to another sheet to the row that corresponds to the value of a column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a spreadsheet, I have 3 source tabs where I fill in comments in the range L4:P.
I would like to copy the comments from these 3 tabs to another tab which would be the target tab, to the row that corresponds to the value in column "H".

In my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTSTb8MlLyncgaEAPY5GwEeRY0qGy7B8UbuzjpiXZEI/edit#gid=0), the source tabs are: "DATA", "EPHAD" and "LIVRET". And the target tab is "COMMENTAIRES".

Here is pictures of what you want:

[image: source tab]

[image: target tab]

Comment: Sorry I can't fully understand what you want to do. Can you share sample screenshots from the input and the desired result?

Comment: I added pictures in my answer

Comment: In tabs : "DATA", "EPHAD" and "LIVRET" each range L4:P, I want onEdit fonction. And only the edited cell pasted in "COMMENTAIRES" tab in same column as the source tab but in row where the value in column "H" in source tab matche with the value in in column "H" in target tab ("COMMENTAIRES")

Comment: @Dan F Tell me if you need more explanations

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I have posted an answer according to what you said. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var shName = sourceSheet.getName();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COMMENTAIRES");
  
  if ((shName == "DATA" || shName == "EPHAD" || shName == "LIVRET" )&& (row > 4 && col >= 12 || col <= 16)){
    var dataToCopy = range.getValue();
    var email = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();
    var destRow = destSheet.createTextFinder(email).findNext().getRow();
    destSheet.getRange(destRow,col).setValue(dataToCopy);
  }
}
```

**Result:**

DATA Sheet

[image]

LIVRET Sheet
[image]

**Explanation:**
Using the onEdit trigger you can make use of the (e) event to get the details of the edited cell like it's row and column. Then on the same row get the value from the column H. Then use the `findNext()` textFinder to find the **match email** on the tab "COMMENTAIRES" and paste it on the same row. This would work as long as there are no duplicate emails on the destination sheet.

- [findNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findNext())

Comment: It's magic! I've been working on this script for almost 10 hours and it looks a lot simpler than I imagined. I'm going to analyze it well to try to understand and learn... Thanks a lot Dan

Comment: @SavoirApprendre you're welcome, glad to know it's resolved!